# using the oplog monitoring class in casbah

Tags: scala, mongodb, replication, casbah

I am trying to use the oplog monitoring class in casbah

https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-core/src/main/scala/util/OpLog.scala

What i want to do is monitor the oplog entries at a production mongo db on

```
 production.someserver.com
```

and get the entries and send them to the storage DB at

```
 test.someotherserver.com
```

and replicate all the data that is in the production server to the test server. I cannot use replica sets to do this as i cannot redeploy now. I am trying to build a scala app to do this. Casbah the official scala driver for mongo as the above mentioned class which i m trying to instantiate using

```
val mongoColl = MongoConnection() ("test") ("test_data")
val oLog = new MongoOpLog(mongoColl)
```

But im not even able to instantiate it, getting an error that mongooplog is not found. Ive imported the necessary package. But even if im able to do this i have no clue on how to do what i want to do. can any one pls point me in a right direction on how to achieve this. I am pretty new to scala so a bit of detailed explanation or a link containing it would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have replication enabled on the server for the oplog to be created; as either a member of a replica set or in master mode for master/slave.

Otherwise, MongoDB does not waste CPU cycles and disk space maintaining an oplog. Please see the documentation on Replication for more info - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication

You should really never be running any database with a single server in production, incidentally.

Comment: The oplog is already created, and its working fine. I just need to know how i can monitor it programatically using scala and casbah, i have no idea on how to use the oplog monitoring class to do what i need, i have clearly explained what i need to do.

Comment: You need to paste the entire error message you are getting then.  My confusion comes from you saying " getting an error that mongooplog is not found " which is a message I do spit out from the class when I cannot find the oplog.  Additionally, the first argument to MongoOpLog is a CONNECTION, not a Collection, which you are passing in.

Comment: No the error is flagged by the IDE. im using IntelliJ IDEA and while compiling itself im getting the error that the class mongooplog is not found.

Comment: which method should i call to start monitoring the oplog in the oplog monitor and how do i get the record that is writen to the oplog